# How to forbid using property setter?

Tags: c#

```
[KnownType(typeof(B))]
public abstract class A: IA //  string Description { get; }
{
      [DataMember(Name = "description")]
      public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public sealed class B: A
{
    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return "Custom_Description";
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot change my abstract class and I want to forbid using `set` in `Description` like:

```
B b = new B();
b.Description = "description";
```

How to do that? How can I implement `set`?

Comment: Strange that you cannot change your abstract class A when writing B. Clearly somebody could, as they added `[KnownType(typeof(B))]` to it...

Comment: Note that this violates the [L of SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The proper way would be to change the abstract base.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Thanks, how to change the abstract base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option is to throw a NotSupportedException in the set accessor:

```
public sealed class B : A {
    public override string Description {
        get {
            return "Custom_Description";
        }
        set {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get a compile error, instead, that's not possible, as you cannot 
change the accessibility of the `set` method in `B`. Even if you could, someone could cast your instance of `B` to a type `A` and call set on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways.

1. Just make setter protected.

   ```
   public abstract class A: IA
   {
        public virtual string Description { get; protected set; }
   }
   ```

   This guarantees that 90% of your code can't set Description. But in inheritors of class A you still can try to *set Description*. And it's compile-time safety
2. Replace original auto-property to abstract property without setter. 
   Then in class B write implementation for that. And in some another class you can create backing field if you want to have ability to set/get property. This is more secure way, but it can lead you to redudant copy-paste code.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in you abstract class I think it cannot be done.
An ugly work around would be:

```
public sealed class B: A
{
    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return "Custom_Description";
        }
        set
        {
           throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also discard (take it, but not use it) the value in the setter